# Code hint problem with addEventListener in javascript

Tags: javascript

My code works well, but Dreamweaver code hint says there is a syntax error at line "node.addEvent ...". Can you tell me how to prevent this ? Is there a best way to write it ?

```
const node = document.getElementById(info);
        node.addEventListener("keydown", ({key}) => {
            if (key === "Enter") {
                $('#submit_'+info).click();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please don't *describe* error messages. Instead, *copy and paste* them so we can see exactly what the error is. There's no syntax error in the code in the question. Odd indentation, ;-) but no syntax error.

Comment: As you've mention a syntax error it'll be good to share that in the question.